# Print String in form of unicode codes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, unicode

Is there some method I can call on `"hello"` to get `'\u0068\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f'`?

Comment: @EdwardFalk I was iterating through each character, using `#ord` to get the numeric representation, and then using `rjust(4, '0')` and prepending `'\u'`. It was working, I was just hoping that a method existed for doing it all in one (short) line.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. `String#codepoints` returns these in an array of integers:

```
"hello".codepoints #=> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

If you need it as escape sequences, try this:

```
"hello".codepoints.map {|c| "\\u#{sprintf("%04x", c)}"}.join
```

And if you want another solution (credit to @MattyK in comments):

```
"hello".codepoints.map{|c| '\u%04X' % c}.join
```

Comment: Or if you prefer slightly fewer symbols:  "hello".codepoints.map{|c| '\u%04X' % c}.join

Comment: @MattyK: Good point. Forgot you could do that in Ruby too, not just python.

Comment: @MattyK I actually liked your version best, so I added it to _Linuxios_' answer and chose it.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: Just so you know, it's SE policy to only let the owner of the post add new content to their post. I'm happy to add it, that's just why your edit was rejected.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: Sure. Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
"hello".unpack('U*').map{ |i| "\\u" + i.to_s(16).rjust(4, '0') }.join
=> "\\u0068\\u0065\\u006c\\u006c\\u006f"
```